# PHPStorm, automatic upload: always overwriting

Tags: ftp, phpstorm

I have created a new Deployment in PHPStorm's settings, with automatic upload. Working perfectly fine, I am just wondering where the option is to have PHPStorm check whether the file on the server is newer and when two people are working on the same file et cetera.

How can I add that piece of functionality in PHPStorm?

Answer (score 6):

> to have PHPStorm check whether the file on the server is newer

**`Settings (Preferences on Mac) | Deployment | Options`** (or the same via `Tools | Deployment | Options`)

- `Overwrite up-to-date files` to skip upload if file is up-to-date
- `Warn when uploading over newer file` -- chose option other than "No"

---

> and when two people are working on the same file et cetera

There is no such option (like Dreamweaver has, for example) -- this IDE was not designed to work this way. PhpStorm is built around the idea of using local files with ability to upload them to remote location (be it dev/test server (main purpose) or production server).

If you have more than one person working on the same files at the same time .. and you do not want to overwrite each other work -- **consider using  any of the popular VCS** (git/mercurial/svn/etc) -- PhpStorm supports a lot of them (all popular for sure).